# Apache VFS SFTP moveTo command fails

Tags: java, apache, sftp, jsch, vfs

I am using Apache vfs sftp to copy a file to remote linux box and then rename it.
copy works fine, but when  i try to rename the file, it fails.
I am using vfs 2.0 and jsch 0.1.50

```
Source(remoteFileTmp)       : /tmp/abc.txt
Destination(remoteFileDest) : /home/myName/work/abc.txt
```

Command that I used is as below:

```
remoteFileTmp.moveTo(remoteFileDest);
```

The exception that i get is as below:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not rename "sftp://hostname/tmp/abc.txt" to "sftp://hostname/home/myName/work/abc.txt".
    at com.transfer.SFTPTransfer.uploadRename(SFTPTransfer.java:85)
    at com.transfer.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:23)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not rename "sftp://hostname/tmp/abc.txt" to "sftp://hostname/tmp/abc.txt" to "sftp://hostname/home/myName/work/abc.txt".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.moveTo(AbstractFileObject.java:1116)
    at com.transfer.SFTPTransfer.uploadRename(SFTPTransfer.java:59)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: 4: Failure
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2833)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.rename(ChannelSftp.java:1910)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileObject.doRename(SftpFileObject.java:289)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.moveTo(AbstractFileObject.java:1102)
    ... 2 more
```

Directory /home/myName/work exists.

Note: when i try to move (rename) files in the same folder it works fine.
i.e for the below input rename is succesfful.

```
source = /tmp/abc.txt
destination = /tmp/abc.txt_renamed
```

So is it that it supports rename only within the same directory?

Comment: Correction in the 4th line of the error pasted. It is ------ Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not rename "sftp://hostname/tmp/abc.txt" to "sftp://hostname/home/myName/work/abc.txt".

Comment: Have you tried to rename it to any other subdirectory of the same folder or any other folder in the same file system?

Comment: Yes,, renaming worked when i used a sub-directory of the same folder. I did not try any other thing as we decided we will use a sub-directory within the same folder.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by one of the open issues in the Apache VFS library when doing moveTo over SFTP :-(

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VFS-590

and this

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VFS-589